# Angular 4 - using ngModel inside (click)

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have the following html:

```
<div class="workflow-row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="new-workflow" [(ngModel)]="new_checkbox"> 
    <label>New Workflow</label>
    <input type="text" *ngIf="new_checkbox" placeholder="Enter Workflow Name">
</div>  
<div class="workflow-row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="edit-workflow" [(ngModel)]="edit_checkbox"> 
    <label>Edit Workflow</label>
    <select *ngIf="edit_checkbox"></select>
</div>
```

I want the checkboxes to act like radio buttons, ie: if one is checked, the other one becomes unchecked with angular 4. I tried doing

```
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-workflow" (click)="new_checkbox.checked = false" 
[(ngModel)]="edit_checkbox">
```

but I get an error and it says that new_checkbox is undefined. The weird thing is that `new_checkbox` and `edit_checkbox` work inside the **ngIf** statements but not inside the `(click)`'s. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: fixed. unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to try the following:

**component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent {
    edit_checkbox = false;
    new_checkbox = true;

    dropNewValue() {
        this.new_checkbox = false;
    }

    dropEditValue() {
        this.edit_checkbox = false;
    }
}
```

Then in your template file, e.g. **component.html**, change your template slightly to:

```
<div class="workflow-row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="new-workflow" [(ngModel)]="new_checkbox" (ngModelChange)="dropEditValue()">
    <label>New Workflow</label>
    <input type="text" *ngIf="new_checkbox" placeholder="Enter Workflow Name">
</div>
<div class="workflow-row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="edit-workflow" [(ngModel)]="edit_checkbox" (ngModelChange)="dropNewValue()">
    <label>Edit Workflow</label>
    <select *ngIf="edit_checkbox"></select>
</div>
```

I've just tried this and it works. However I do recommend to switch to radio buttons approach, because you will get the same behavior out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write Angular like you're writing regular `javascript` instead of

```
(click)="new_checkbox.checked = false"
```

do something like

```
// .html
(click)="uncheckNewCheckbox()"

// .js or .ts
uncheckNewCheckbox() {
  this.new_checkbox.checked = false;
}
```

Comment: it's saying new_checkbox doesn't exist in the component class.

Comment: And that wasn't part of your question, you asked why it doesn't work and I told you why from the info you provided, maybe also read up on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask